# mySQL synchronise certain rows from two tables - copy data and update

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, certain rows of which need to be synchronised at different times.

What is the cleanest way to copy rows from one table to another while preserving the primary keys of both tables?

At present I'm using the two queries shown below but I'm occasionally getting errors like this: `Duplicate entry '465' for key 1`

```
DELETE * FROM t2 WHERE instanceID='10'

INSERT INTO t2 (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE instanceID='10')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY SET` clause to copy the columns when there's a duplicate.

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE <condition>
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = t1.col1, col2 = t1.col2, col3 = t1.col3, ...
```

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. It's a big table tho. There's no shortcut to typeing each column name individually?

Comment: This works well using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` rather than `ON DUPLICATE KEY SET`. Thanks a lot Barmar